# How to use a dynamic color for angular span

Tags: html, angular

I am getting error for using this variable as a color in my html file

```
 <span style=`color: ${_currentConfig.statusColor};`>{{ _currentConfig?.content }}</span>
```

Whats wrong here ? `main.js:1 DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '${_currentConfig.statusColor};`' is not a valid attribute name.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Angular's binding syntax to dynamically set the style. Here's an example :

```
<span [style.color]="_currentConfig?.statusColor">{{ _currentConfig?.content }}</span>
```